# Book about a 10/11 year old boy with autism or something similar

Tags: identification-request

This middle-grade novel was from sometime between 2000 and 2016, I believe. It was by an American or British author, who died before 2016, as mentioned on the back cover.

- The protagonist was a 10/11 year old boy who described his mind as being wired differently, like a computer with a different operating system; later he said he had a mental disorder such as autism or Asperger's.

  - He was from the US.
- He made a friend with a boy of a similar age from England.
- The British boy had a sister, I believe, and maybe was related to the main character.
- This friend frequently used the British slang word "mosher", saying something like it meant "a right cool dude".
- I think it maybe took place in England.

  - If it did, there was some sort of a scene where the characters went on the London Eye, but that is likely confused with another book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably *The London Eye Mystery* (2007) by Siobhan Dowd, who passed away the same year.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1184305.The_London_Eye_Mystery):

> Monday, 24 May, 11.32 a.m. **Ted and Kat watch their cousin Salim get on board the London Eye.** He turns and waves and the pod rises from the ground.
>
> Monday, 24 May, 12.02 p.m. The pod lands and the doors open. People exit in all shapes and sizes – but where is Salim?
>
> Ted and his older sister Kat become sleuthing partners since the police are having no luck. Despite their prickly relationship, they overcome their differences to follow a trail of clues across London in a desperate bid to find their cousin. And ultimately **it comes down to Ted, whose brain runs on its own unique operating system,** to find the key to the mystery.

[Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=jiHLr3_KQyQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA54) offers the following quote about mosher and being cool:

> 'Salim's a mosher, I said.
>
> 'A mosher?'
>
> "It's northern for "casual, cool dude", I said.

---

Found with the Google query `book mind "wired differently" "mosher"` which returned
[this page](http://www.unc.edu/world/2010PartnersWS/ABCsofDiversity6-12.pdf), which is taken down, but the Google preview read:

> “The ABC's of Diversity”
>
> A Selective Bibliography of Multicultural Books for Students in Grades 6-12 ... the two siblings must work together-Ted with his brain that is "wired differently".